# Installing and Using jQuery Toolbox

Tags: jquery, html, visual-studio

I have never designed a webpage before, but I am asked to do this and will be using jQuery. I was wondering, what is the best and easiest way to do this? I thought of doing this on Visual Studio using only jQuery and HTML controls to produce an html page without any asp.net controls. Is this possible? How can I get this? And if you have any further suggestions, I'll be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find [jQuery here](http://jquery.com/)

And yes you can build a pure HTML web page unless you need some persistent information in which case you might handle that with Ajax.

But for a larger site it could get very complex.

Visual Studio 2010 had great intellisence for jQuery to but more than that I cannot say without more information on what the site is going to do :)

Comment: Briefly, it's a search page. The search results are displayed in the middle and divided into two different types, each on a tab.

On the left and right, probably some links will be displayed.

Comment: You could build the basic structure in pure HTML and then use jQuery UI widgets or custom code to add listings fetched from the server by ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, should be a great result.

Briefly, Jquery is best loaded via CDN.  It'll load faster than a self-hosted bit of code and eliminates the need for you to manage updates on your server.  There's no charge and code is [available from several different network](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery)s.

Answer (score 0):

Not an uncommon issue with new web developers. I recently explained it pretty thoroughly in a related question. Here is the link:

- **[StackOverflow - How to Implement jQuery and Optimize Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725361/turning-two-elements-visible-hidden-in-same-div/17726550#answer-17726550)**

---